# How to add the diagonal line on a ROC curve plot from PRROC?

Tags: r, roc

Here is a sample of ROC curve in PRROC

```
library(PRROC)
# create artificial scores as random numbers
x <- rnorm( 1000 );
y <- rnorm( 1000, -1 );

# compute area under PR curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y );
print( pr );

# compute area under ROC curve
roc <- roc.curve( x, y );
print( roc );

# compute PR curve and area under curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
# plot curve
plot(pr);

# compute ROC curve and area under curve
roc <- roc.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
# plot curve
plot(roc);
```

I want to add a diagonal line in this original plot with colorful line but the coordinate is always wrong.

Comment: Looking at the vignette, there seem to be `min.plot` & `rand.plot` arguments. One of those might work.

Comment: @gung hi, could you please describe vignette in detail, I do not find any information about min.plot & rand.plot arguments. Thank you

Comment: @gung it works, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked, @ChensonYu.  I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have that package, and haven't used it.  That said, I see that there is a vignette listed on the CRAN site.  Looking at the vignette, there seem to be `min.plot` and `rand.plot` arguments. Since the diagonal line on a ROC plot represents the minimum value / how a completely random model should perform in the long run, one of those might create the line you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work. Provided you have ggplot2 package installed.

if you dont have ggplot2 installed.
run this code first

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

and then run below code

```
library(PRROC)
# create artificial scores as random numbers
x <- rnorm( 1000 );
y <- rnorm( 1000, -1 );

data = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
# compute area under PR curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y );
print( pr );

# compute area under ROC curve
roc <- roc.curve( x, y );
print( roc );

# compute PR curve and area under curve
pr <- pr.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
# plot curve
plot(pr);

# compute ROC curve and area under curve
roc <- roc.curve( x, y, curve = TRUE );
# plot curve
plot(roc)

library(ggplot2)
data <- as.data.frame(roc$curve)
data <- data[,1:2]
ggplot(data, aes(x=data$V1, y=data$V2))+geom_line()+ geom_abline(slope = 1)
```

Comment: this way do not save the original form from PRROC, I want to keep the color roc curve from PRROC and add a diagonal line in the original plot.